# fetch records without using a button

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have write this simple coding to fetch customer name and address based on the mobile number (user provided mobile number). I have done this succesfully with **Fetch button**. But I need to do **without a button** option.

When user entered mobile number in textfield then they will go to the next field (name). If mobile number already exists in database customer name and address should fetch from database. If mobile number not exists they will enter remaining two fields. Any help?

```
require('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $cmobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $cname = $_POST['name'];
    $caddress = $_POST['address'];

    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO autocomplete ( mobile, name, address ) VALUES ( :cmobile, :cname, :caddress )");
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam(':cmobile', $cmobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cname', $cname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':caddress', $caddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($stmt)
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['fetch']))
{
    $cmobile = $_POST['mobile'];

    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM autocomplete WHERE mobile = :cmobile");
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam(':cmobile', $cmobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $aname = $row['name'];
            $aaddress = $row['address'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
    if($stmt)
    {
        echo "fetch success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fetch error";
    }
}
```

and

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
    mobile number : <input type="text" name="mobile" /><br />
    name : <input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $aname ?>" /><br />
    address : <input type="text" name="address" value="<?= $aaddress ?>" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <button name="fetch">Fetch</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it using jQuery.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Just make simple function for that.

Comment: You are partially right. But instead of `mouseleave()`, it must be `blur`.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as they can break. Please pull relevant information from your links into this answer so that the information is available, even if the link is not.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is opting Ajax. You can fill the data without page refresh.

```
$('input[name="mobile"]').blur(function(e)
{
  mobile=$(this).val();
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "PAGE_URL_TO_GET_NEW_DATA",
    data: {mobile: mobile},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('input[name="name"]').val(data.name);
      $('input[name="address"]').val(data.address);
    }
  }
});
```

And in your PHP page, use `json_encode` instead of simple `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work. But to do this asynchronously will be a little more difficult.
You will probably have to use some ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#fetch").hide();
$("input").blur(function(){
   $("#fetch").click();
});
});
```

Comment: by hiding the submit button, it will also be a fail safe if js is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

There are some different events you can add to the text field in html:

If you've got HTML5:

- `oninput` (fires only when a change actually happens, but does so immediately)

Otherwise:

- `onchange`
- `onkeyup` (not keydown or keypress as the input's value won't have the
  new keystroke in it yet)
- `onpaste` (when supported)

So you could use a javascript action to fire on key up of the text field which would need to check the length of the mobile number field and when it reaches the right amount of numerals to do the php fetch.

An example using an inline script: ****

```
    <script>
    function showInfo(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","MYPHPFILE.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="showInfo(this.value);">
    mobile number : <input type="text" name="mobile" onKeyUp="showInfo(this.value);">
  <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <button name="fetch">Fetch</button>
</form>

    <br>
    <div id="txtResult"><b>RESULTS FROM PHP WILL BE DISPLAYED HERE</b></div>
```

**** I would recommend looking at using a library eg Dojo for cleaner Ajax methods or AT-LEAST making the script in an external JavaScript file and possibly a method with parameters to call the ajax so you can reuse it throughout your site to call other things too.

So this is an rough example of JavaScript (Excluding the if statement) which is is called on key up of the mobile field if you look at the field you can see the onkeyup calling the method and passing the value of the mobile number.

Add an if statement to check how many numerals have been entered so far (by getting the value of the current innerhtml for that element and checking the length then executing the ajax if the length is right) before executing that Ajax so it only checks once the field is fully entered.

Now I'm assuming your config.php is your file with DB connection so ill leave out the connection stuff.

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM registeredUsers WHERE mobile = $q";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

So this php method called in the JavaScript and passing the mobile number as "q" and will look for users name and address with a mobile number as passed.

This method requires you have some sort of registeredUsers table with mobile name and address fields to get the information from.

If so it will return the table with their name and address back to your page. All without refreshing... MAGIC! - There are much more efficient ways of doing this in today's world however a method like this will work for example and I hope this helps you get your head around it and get it working.

Comment: Yes james. Can you tell me the ajax solution with some explanation?

Comment: Have edited answer with some more detailed information and relating example.

Comment: This is invalid `WHERE mobile = :q";` Placeholders as such are for PDO and not `mysqli_*`. You're thinking more like `WHERE mobile = ?";` then using `bind_param()` But in this case, it would need to be `WHERE mobile = $q";`